The Principle of Homogeneity of dimensions states that you can add,subtract quantities with same dimensions but we cannot add a constant with an angle
Both a constant and a plane and solid angle are dimensionless ie they have the same dimensions , so according to principle of homogeneity should you not be able to equate them ?
But it would be absurd to state 60 degrees = 5

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$60,\mathrm{deg}=\pi/3,$ not $5.$

60 deg is pi/3 degrees , my doubt is according to principle of homogeneity since a constant ie a pure number is dimensionless and so is plane angle can you equate them

@Aryan, $\pi / 3$ is radians, not degrees (different angle measurement unit).

my bad that was a typo but my doubt still remains

"Just because you could, doesn't mean you should". There are infinitely many mathematical operations you can do with physical quantities that don't make sense. If you want to add two quantities together, you should know why you are doing that, so that the operation makes sense.

As another example, if I want to calculate something related to the Earth's orbit around the sun, I would very well add the velocity of the Sun relative to centre of the Milky Way, and 14 times the velocity of Earth relative to Mars, and still get something with dimensions velocity. It is also absurd, bith the procedure and the answer.

Dimensional homogeneity principle should be interpreted like so,- that you can't compare or equate two quantities if they have different dimensions (like distance to speed). If they have same dimensions,- it could be compared, but "comparison integrity" is still not guaranteed by this principle. I.e. it's weak statement.
For example, both torque and energy share same dimensions- $[T^{−2}L^{2}M]$, however you still can't add torque to energy (or work) or compare them, because they physical meaning is completely different. Hence things are a bit more complicated, and dimensional homogeneity in not enough to ensure smooth operations on quantities. You basically need to know physical meaning of quantity also.
